# Django: Push app from local server to production server via FTP

Tags: python, django, ftp, server

This is a bit embarassing, but I'm a Django noob and I couldn't find a simple solution to this:

I have written a Django app in a local VM that I now want to deploy to a "production" server. App works like a charm locally.

Now my IT colleague has set up the server with Django and that also works fine. I can open it via the Web and I get the usual "Congratulations on your first Django-powered page". I can also log into the admin interface. The project has been created.

This is a very low-key mini project and I'm not too familiar with git, so we've decided to just push files via FTP. (And I want to stick with that if at all possible.) So I uploaded the app folder into the project folder and also adjusted the project's settings.py and urls.py.

However, nothing seems to be happening on the server's end. The welcome page is the same, the app does not show up in the admin interface and the URLs won't be resolved as hoped.

Any suggestions what I should have done / done differently?

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart apache or whatever is running your django project. Your changes to py files are cached when you first load your server config (settings).

> Any suggestions what I should have done / done differently?

You should be using git/jenkins/deployment techniques, I know you said you've decided not to use it but you're going to be missing out on important things like being able to keep track of changes and unit testing

Comment: Thanks. We will use git eventually; right now I need to get this done before Christmas.

Does the server not take the changes automatically? When I work on it locally (on a Windows 10 machine) the Python-"internal" server automatically refreshes/restarts.

Comment: @D.Joe - You'll be surprised at how quickly you could get a git repo up and running, use bitbucket/github or something similar if you really want to, along side sourcetree

Comment: @D.Joe - The server takes the updated .py files but the actual project will be running on the `pyc` files, settings are also loaded at this time so they're not reread